# Handlebar stolen along with gear shifter and brake triggers. What to do how much am i looking to spend?

Tags: brakes, repair, gears, parts

So live in Redfern, Sydney, Australia. I keep my bike at my dad's and he asked me to lock my bike near the police station for a while because he was fixing up his apartment. This was before I left on holidays. He messages me that he checked on the bike and that while the bike is intact, the handlebars were missing. To which I exclaimed as handlebars I imagine are easy to replace. The gears and wheels and pedals are still intact.

But then he added the brake levers and gear shifters are missing. Now I'm sure brake levers and specially gear shifters are going to be a pain but I'm not sure how much of a pain. My bike is a $400/$500 Malvern Star (Australian brand) hybrid with Shimano parts.

How much will this repair cost?

Comment: Note that thieves will often disable a bike so you aren't able to ride it home in order to buy time so that they can steal the rest of it.

Comment: Guessing that the cables were all cut, so you'll need new inners and outers for brakes and gears.  Lucky they weren't Hydraulic.

Comment: You should get the remains of the bike to a more-secure place as soon as possible.  Locking up outside overnight, for days on end is a bad idea.  Not like the proximity of a police station helps at all, if anything, its somewhere the light-fingered have to go for whatever reason, so you've chosen one of the worst parking locations for your bike..

Comment: A handlebar is an odd thing to steal.  I'm guessing that the thief unbolted the stem from the bike, in order to steal the shifters and brake levers.  So you probably also need a new stem.  Your best bet is to find another bike you can scavenge parts from (though I suggest you pay for the donor bike rather than simply passing along the "favor" to another sucker).  You will almost certainly need new cables as well, but those are relatively cheap and generic.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know about Australia but here in Austria a cheap 9/3 speed Shimano Alivio combined brake lever + shifter can be had for 18.95€. Add another 20€ or so for the handlebar and you end up around 60€ for the repair.

This assumes your bike uses mechanical brakes and 9-speed MTB gears. 10 speed will be more expensive. Hydraulic equipment and refilling hydraulic brakes will be more expensive as well.